# Why there is no compilation error when throwing null?

Tags: java, exception

I saw one reference for a code in Java which had a line:

```
throw null;
```

I tried the same and there is no compilation exception, till now I thought we can only throw exception, I tested that I can throw any number or Object. Why I am not getting compilation exception? 
If I try to throw String it gives the below exception what does this means?

```
No exception of type String can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
```

Can anyone please explain the reason and use cases where I can use the above code line?

```
class Solution {
    public int repeatedNTimes(int[] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 1; ++ i) {
            if (A[i] == A[i + 1]) { // any two neighbour numbers 
                return A[i];
            }            
        }
        // could be evenly distributed excluding the above case
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 2; ++ i) {
            if (A[i] == A[A.length - 1] || A[i] == A[A.length - 2]) {
                return A[i];
            }
        }
        throw null; // input array is not what has been described
    }
}
```

Comment: That will crash with an NPE at runtime. I suppose this is allowed because java allows one to use a Throwable *expression* with `throw`

Comment: Just to clarify _why_ does compiler allow that: `null` is a subclass of every type, that means, including `Throwable`.

Comment: null isn't a class, let alone a subclass of every type.

Comment: To expand on @ernest_k's comment, when you throw, you usually throw an instance of an exception (as in `throw new IllegalStateException();`), not "an exception". It's like asking why you can pass `null` to an ipothetical `void a(Whatever b)` method. It's syntactically valid. As valid as `IllegalStateException e = new IllegalStateException(); throw e;` What if `e` was declared as `IllegalStateException e = null;`? Nothing would change, syntactically.

Comment: from the original question, And if the ```Expression``` evaluates to ```null```, then a ```NullPointerException``` is thrown. Specifically,
```
If evaluation of the Expression completes normally, producing a null value, then an instance V' of class NullPointerException is created and thrown instead of null.```  is this the reason String/Number type exception can't be thrown. As they can't be mapped to ay exception?